# Take id from mysql table table with springboot and concatenate with url

Tags: mysql, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have hardcoded below id to be 1 but i need to fetch the id from the employeedetails table of EMPLOYEE database

```
int id=1; //This id needs to come from table from column id


public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {   
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "/applyleave/"+ id);
}

@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMPLOYEE");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    return dataSource;
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
    .jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource()).usersByUsernameQuery("select user_id, password, loginstatus from employeedetails where user_id=? ").authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_id, role from employeedetails where user_id=? ");
}
```

How can i achieve this with spring boot java configuration ??

Comment: Write one query method in employeee. Which will find out all the entries in employee table. Then call that method in your above code. Then set you id as employee.getid() and pass it where ever you want

Comment: I have this code in DAO, but i cannot call this method from main java file :  How can i call this method on the above java code 
`public Integer getidforuserId(String userId) {
  return (Integer) entityManager.createQuery("select id from Employee where userId like :userId ").setParameter("userId", userId).getSingleResult();
 }`

Comment: I am not getting your code properly but if you want then I can share my idea about how to use such id from different table

Comment: Can you please do that for me to get the employee Id from database and assign to a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever I understood from your question I have one solution 
write one your employee query in **EmployeeDAO**
Here Employee is your entity class for all getter setter methods

```
public Employee getByUserId(Integer userId) {

//return your query for userId here

}
```

then call this class in your user class where you have to use employee id

```
@Autowired
EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

  Employee employee = employeeDAO.getByUserId(//pass your user id here)
   id = employee.getId();

   registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
   registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "/applyleave/"+ id);
}
```

In this way you can use employeeId here.

Comment: My EmployeeDAOImpl
`public Integer getidforuserId(String userId) {
  return (Integer) entityManager.createQuery("select id from Employee where userId like :userId ").setParameter("userId", userId).getSingleResult();
 }`

My Class code:
`@Autowired
 private static EmployeeDaoImpl employeedaoimpl;`

`public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
Employee employee=employeedaoimpl.getByUserID("vikram.mscsw@gmail.com");
  id=employee.getId();`

But i get the following exception:

Comment: `public Employee getidforuserId(String userId) { .... }`  declare all getter setter in your `Employee` class so that you can use its value in another method

Comment: I have getter setter method in Employee class already but i get a exception whenever i use 

`employee=employeedaoimpl.getByUserID("vikram.mscsw@gmail.com"); id=employee.getId();`

Comment: Why you are passing your email address in `getByUserId` method, here you have to pass `id`,

Comment: No my login form has email address (i.e) UserId and password and when i pass this email address as a arguement it will return an corresponding employee ID of that email id.

Comment: ok then its good, now what's the problem ? what error you are getting.. ?

Comment: The Exception is :
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'viewControllerHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvc
Configuration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested excep
tion is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instanti
ate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'viewContro
llerHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerEx
ception`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104799/discussion-between-vikram-and-ojus-kulkarni).

Comment: maybe you missed some annotations, `@Configuration @EnableWebMvc @Profile("container")` while creating mvc configurations

Answer (score 0):

This method is the controller solved the issue.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getid() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String userid = auth.getName();
        int id=employeeDaoImpl.getIdByUserId(userid);
        return "redirect:/applyleave/"+id;
    }
```

Thanks guys !!!